# How should I have asked?

Tags: support

I have a problem. I need to know if there is a possibility to use gold to improve my character without buying magic items or using a wish. Actually I know that there is at least one combination of spells that would work, and I am wondering if there is any other alternative.

I have asked [a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49122/what-to-do-with-100-000gp-and-no-item-purchase-available) about this, which was closed for being too broad/opinion based, and even after several edits, I couldn't manage to make it acceptable.

Now my problem is still unsolved so in last resort I am posting there, so that you can tell me how should I ask the question so that it will be acceptable here?

Comment: Your current version of the question has two reopen votes. You're worried about people being too hasty to hold, except we're supposed to be hasty: questions put on hold give them time to be fixed up, and the sooner they're put on hold the less mess is created in the answers. Now your question is edited, and at least two high-rep voters think it's improved enough to count as fixed. Don't be too hasty to assume the hold and edit aren't working.

Comment: The main problem right now is you have no criteria for "improve your character" or what they might need once they get there (without any gear at all, I guess)?  What kind of character? Upping your AC is more or less useful depending on whether you're a tank, archer, or wizard... Are there any table-stakes (we'll need to breathe water while we're there...)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie One of the two votes is mine, so that's only one voter since I didn not vote to put my own question on hold

Comment: @mxyzplk you are speaking like there would be hundreds of possibilities. But I read a lot and did not found anything so far but the possibilities I already listed. I am expecting two or three suggestions at most. I don't see how that would be too broad, or else I am missing a big something.

Comment: If I agreed with that, the question would be open. You need to say what you would want out of spells cast on you (Enhance fighting? Survivability in unknown planar environments?)  and then the question is more answerable. Otherwise it's a list of every permanent or permanencable spell, which you can look up yourself without asking here.

Comment: Okay so you are basically telling me that aside using permanency there is no other way. That's all I was asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, you still don't seem to understand why more information was needed for this to be an acceptable question.

Other people don't have all the context you do.  Therefore without some parameters about the situation, they will waste their time giving pointless answers - like the guy who had to delete his big ol' answer because you finally got around to explaining "oh our custom time travel doesn't work that way."  Even Brian's graft etc. suggestions I'm not sure will work in this situation, tattoos and grafts and stuff should go if it's really terminator mode but you're not even sending your body back, just your spirit, as it took a whole week for you to mention.

Just saying "100k, no gear" doesn't make an optimization question good.  "Optimize me!" OK, here's a way to use that to get +10 to WIS.  Is that good for your character?  Or not? hard to tell if you can't be arsed to say what class and level you are. We have general guidance on optimization questions here for that reason.  Optimize what exactly, for what purpose exactly?

When you say "time travel to the distant past," that could mean "you're all popping out in dinosaur times, no civilization around, food and water and normal swords will be a challenge to get."

The question still has a bit too much on what doesn't help (your byzantine time travel plot) and a bit too little on what you need to do. When you drop back into your level 1 body, were you fighting vampires in Karrnath? Or just hanging out and conducting courtly intrigue in Breland?

The question doesn't have to be long, it just has to have the important parts in it. Here's an example that wouldn't have been closed and would probably only have needed a couple clarification comments before people could answer effectively.

"I am a level 12 human swashbucker that specializes in two-weapon fighting and diplomacy. In two weeks I and my party will be traveling back in time - our souls will move back to inhabit our first level bodies from 30 years ago. We can't take gear with us, though intelligent items' spirits will come back with us and can go into gear of the time. Body modifications like tattoos won't travel but permanent spells, inherent bonuses, and things like that will. When we will go back, we will be based in courtly society in Breland but also doing cross-country adventuring, trying to survive for three years and change the past by killing the vampire king of Korrath.

I have 100,000 gp to spend. What can I do in the two weeks I have to enhance myself for this trip?"

That doesn't require lengthy explanation,  it just requires insertion of the facts that bear on your problem.

In the end, if you ask questions that make people go on fishing expeditions, a) they get closed and reopened, b) people write answers that have to get rewritten and/or deleted, and c) eventually people decide that maybe answering your questions is more trouble than it's worth. So it's in your best interest to learn how to ask effective questions.

In fact, it's worth restating one of our fundamental SE best practices.  Ask about your PROBLEM, not about your SOLUTION.  All the parts you spent actually talking about the parameters of your specific situation and what you want to achieve were valuable. Parts where you assumed a given answer and drilled down into that generally led people down wrong paths. So don't assume an answer or a solution.  Post your problem, with all the appropriate parameters that would rule in/out solutions, and let people answer with the actual solutions.

Comment: If I had asked "is it possible to get permanent enhancements without buying gear, using permanency or a wish", would that have worked? Note That I am not asking what I can do, or how I can do, but only if there is a mere possibility.

Comment: @Epeedefeu Maybe, but then you'd get people suggesting things that wouldn't have been any use to your time travel situation, like applying permanent spells or using that +1 ability score bonus portion of Wish. So it clearly wouldn't have worked _for you_ getting anything useful. Now, that's aside from the fact it'd probably be closed as unclear, because Wish says it does that stuff and the answer's therefore a trivial "yes", so we'd be asking you to go into a bit more detail about why you want to know.

Comment: Never thought I would spend so much time on that question. Thank you for your kindness, I will try to ask more accurate questions in the future

Answer (score 4):

**Too broad simply means too Broad**

When a question is closed for Too broad its because the are too many answers that would be "correct" (not enough requirements to distinguish the right answer from another one) or simply that an appropriate answer to such a question would itself be too long because of all the ground it would need to cover.

Sometimes RPG.SE isn't the right place to ask a question simply because the nature of the question would be better served by ongoing discussion on a forum which SE in general avoids.

Comment: I already know that. I am not asking you to tell me my question is garbage and has not its place there, nor to explain me why it is on hold and what it means. I have a problem, and there are a lot of competent persons around there that could probably help. The only barrier is that the question has been put on hold. I just need help to rephrase it so that it will meet the guidelines

Comment: @Epeedefeu Woah there, nobody is saying it's garbage. There are lots of good questions that *can never* be asked here because the site is designed to help with only certain kinds of problems that it is good at solving. Some questions really just don't fit here, but that doesn't mean they're bad questions.

Comment: @Epeedefeu RPG.SE main chat room is the best approach if you still want help from our users but it's with a question that doesn't fit our format.

Comment: Please tell me when it is crowded then. I am on the Paris time zone and last time I came to the chat, there was almost none in the room.

Comment: @Epeedefeu Most SE users are located in the United States (citation needed) and Paris time is 6 hours ahead of the nearest American timezone (EST).  Given that, your best bet is to aim for the late afternoon/evening of the EST timezone, since early users in other timezones will be arriving just behind the EST timezone (So in Paris, you'd want to join the chat at around 9-10 PM)

Answer (score 4):

Narrow down your criteria.

I know this is the obvious but hear me out.

Right now your question has nothing as to what kind of enhancements you are wanting for your character. There are dozens of builds that can be enhanced in dozens of ways each. Put in some background on your character. Is he a tank, a caster, a striker, what is his Class, race, theme, ect. Tell us what your end goal is and we can help you more.

Right now your only criteria is.

1. Old items.
2. 100,000 gold spending limit
3. 2 weeks to complete the process

Come into the chat and we could help you talk it out if you want.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat

Comment: I think I have been completely misunderstood. I was not asking what type of build to do (at least in the last edit of the post), but if it was even possible except by using a wish or permanency

Comment: @Epeedefeu I did misunderstand. I, and I believe most everyone else, thought you were asking what could you do with the resources you had. You might add somewhere in your questions if it is possible at all.